# How to access custom UITableViewCell from main ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a main view controller with UITableView. Table view have 2 cells prototyped in IB.

[Prototyped Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvWcT.png)

The first cell is in section 0 and the second cell is in section 1 (to be always at the bottom of the table).

Here is my table definition in main ViewController:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
    return itemNames.count
    } else {
    return 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// Created additional section where will be the cell for adding items (always at bottom)
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
    let cellIdentifier = "itemCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

    cell.itemNameTextView.text = itemNames[indexPath.row]
    let currentImage = itemImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemStateButton.setImage(UIImage(named: currentImage), for: UIControlState.normal)

    return cell

    case 1:
    let cellIdentifier = "addItemCell"
    let addCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

    addCell.addItemButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus-math-40"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    return addCell

    default:
    return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

All the Outlets to the cells are defined in custom UITableViewCell:

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var itemNameTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var itemStateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var addItemButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var addTextView: UITextView!
```

How can I access the values (read and change) of outlets variables in ItemTableViewCell from main ViewController?

For example, when "+" button pressed in the second cell, I need to TextView become the FirstResponder, and then save the value of TextFiled.

And also I need to edit the TextFields on the 0 section cells and then save data from them.

Comment: Try [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka).

Answer (score 1):

I've made it with the current cell defined as custom cell instance (it's a code to save data to CoreData when finished editing a TextView in a cell):

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    currentTextView = nil

    // Finished edit tex tin text view. Save new values to CoreData
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: currentIndexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell
    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {

        // Add Mode. Adding values from addItemCell to CoreData
        if editMode == false {
            // In add mode we need to add a new record to CoreData
            // Check if textview is not empty
            if currentCell.addTextView.text != "" {
            shoppingItem = ItemMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            shoppingItem.itemName = currentCell.addTextView.text
            shoppingItem.itemCreatedDate = Date()
            shoppingItem.itemDone = false
            currentCell.addTextView.text = ""
            }
        } else {
            // In edit mode we need to save current values and save context
            if currentCell.itemNameTextView.text != "" {
            shoppingItems[currentIndexPath.row].itemName = currentCell.itemNameTextView.text
            }
            }
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

currentIndexPath value I'm taking when starting editing the cell:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    currentTextView = textView

    var superview = textView.superview
    while let view = superview, !(view is UITableViewCell) {
        superview = view.superview
    }
    guard let cell = superview as? UITableViewCell else {
        //print("button is not contained in a table view cell")
        return
    }
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        //print("failed to get index path for cell containing button")
        return
    }

    // Setup current index path value
    self.currentIndexPath = indexPath

    // Setup edit mode for data saving in textViewDidEndEditing
    if currentIndexPath.section == 0 {
        editMode = true
    } else {
        if currentIndexPath.section == 1 {
            editMode = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 no. of sections and one row in each section, then you can give addItemButton tag value equal to section number. Then add action to that button and define a corresponding selector. In that selector method, get the section value from sender's tag and get the indexpath corresponding to section and row(=0). From that indexpath, get the cell and then you can access any outlet of Cell in Main Controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to

1. Get button press events on the custom `UITableViewCell`
2. Change IBOutlet values from the main `UIViewController`

Firstly to get **button press** events on the cell object, you have 2 options:

1.1 Attach a target when instantiating the cell:

```
// In your tableView cellForRow method
addCell.addItemButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bringUpTextfieldMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
```

1.2 Use a delegate structure: have the `ItemTableViewCell` declare a delegate protocol, capture button press events in this class via an `IBAction` outlet, and pass up the event using the delegate. The main ViewController conform to the protocol and implement the delegate callback.

Secondly - accessing the IBOutlets of the cell. Anywhere you need to access the cell:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0) // Obviously with the correct row/sec
let itemCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell  // your tableview must be an IBOutlet on your view controller

// Now you can access properties on itemCell
// e.g:
let name = itemCell.itemNameTextView.text
```